# How to translate box representation to parenthesis representation

Tags: scheme, lisp, common-lisp

I was working on something that was clear for a while but, at some point, I wasn't able to understand.

So I know that this image represents `(a b c x d)`:

[image]

But, what I don't get is what happens for this one:

[image]

Since there is one with nothing on it, which points to two things, how to write with parenthesis that there are two ways with b x and d a

I would write it `(c((b(x))(d(a))))` but I'm not really sure about it.

Thanks for the answer, I appreciate it;

Comment: Please explain which box is problematic when you say "one with nothing on it" and "one which points to two things"; and try to explain step by step how you choose to write the parenthesis notation based on the box representation. Good luck

Comment: When i'm talkign about the one with nothing and the one which points to two things, im basically talking about the same, which is the second one, between c and d. I would write it like that because first we have c then we have nothing so we open up with (, then we have b and on b we have x so we end with (c((b(x)) then we return to the second box, and now we have d and a, which have the same style as b and x so i end up with (c(b x)(d a))

Answer (score 6):

I think the useful way of thinking about these is to realise two things:

- all boxes are cons cells, *aka* pairs;
- there is a slightly unhelpful shorthand being used, and if you redraw the diagram without that shorthand it is easier to translate.

The unhelpful shorthand is that a box which is drawn like this:

[image: implicit]

is, in fact simply this:

[image: explicit]

Where `()` is the unique 'empty-box' object which is traditionally called `nil` in Lisp, but does not have a name (I think) in Scheme as a standard.

So knowing this shorthand you can take the picture you have, which is the same as this one

[image: folded]

and unfold it to this one

[image: unfolded]

So, OK, now you have this unfolded picture, you can simply write down the representation of this as text, remembering that the representation of a cons cell is simply `(l . r)`, say, where `l` and `r` are the left and right elements, and the representation of the empty-box object is `()`.

I'm not going to write down the textual representation of your problem since I don't want to do your homework – I want to explain *how* to do your homework! – but I will write down the representation of this, say:

[image: unfolded-simple]

Well, just following the boxes we get a representation which is

```
((x . ()) . (y . ())
```

Which, oops, isn't anything like the sort of answer you need to get.

But all is not lost.  Now you need to know the final thing: there are three special rules which apply to printing (or reading) trees (graphs) of conses like this.

- **Rule 1.** A cons which is of the form `(<anything> . ())` can be written s `(<anything>)`.
- **Rule 2.** A cons whose *right hand entry* (cdr) is itself a cons can have the dot elided and the right hand cons spliced in.  So `(x . (y . ...))` can be written as `(x y . ...)`, for instance.
- **Rule 3.** When writing cons trees, you usually try and apply rules 1 and 2 to minimise the number of dots in the printed representation.

So let's apply these rules to the above structure.

- we start with `((x . ()) . (y . ())`;
- we can apply rule 1 twice to each half, to get `((x) . (y))`;
- we can now apply rule 2 once, since the right hand side of the top object is a cons, to get `((x) y)`.  And this *is* like the sort of representation you are expected to provide.

As a guide when applying these rules it is best to apply them from the inside out, and to apply all the rule 1's you can followed by the rule 2's.

So in summary the approach I would suggest is:

1. redraw the diagram with the shorthand for `()` removed;
2. read off the cons-tree structure from it as `(... . ...)`;
3. use the rules above to minimize the number of dots in the cons-tree you have written down;
4. profit.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. It was really helpful and clear.

Comment: your rules 1 and 2 are one and the same, syntactically: `(A B ... . ( C ... ))` == `(A B ... C ... )`, removing the dot and the following pair of parentheses together at once, where both `B ...` and `C ...` can be empty sequences.

Comment: @WillNess: I am aware of that.  But my rules tell you how to rewrite things in terms of the semantics of what is there: the cdr of `(a)` is not a cons, so the 'cdr is a cons' rule does not apply.

Answer (score 2):

Start with pairs. Every box is `(x . y)` with `x` and `y` being the parts the box points to. eg. for the first one it's:

```
(a . (b . (c . (x . (d . ())))))
```

Now most lisps will remove the `.` and the parenteses around the `cdr` if they can.. Eg. `(d . ())` => `(d)` and you can apply this simplification all the way such that the above can be displayed:

```
(a b c x d)
```

A missing dot between elements and end means `. (...)` in my head so while I don't see them I imagine the dot notation when looking at it.

The second box notation means clearly this:

```
(c . ((b . (x . ())) . (d . (a . ()))))
```

Now you can do the trick with removing dots if the `cdr` has parentheses in them. I leave that for you to do since you need to do this transformation in your mind both forward and backward. eg. you should be able to look at `((e f) x (i j))` and say `((e . (f . ())) . (x . ((i . (j . ())))))`  and that accessing `j` is `cadaddr` (which might not exist since it is 5 and the requirement is 4 so you can split it up to `(car (cdaddr '((e . (f . ())) . (x . ((i . (j . ()))))))) ; ==> j`)

Answer (score 0):

You can play with https://github.com/cbaggers/draw-cons-tree

```lisp
CL-USER> (ql:quickload "draw-cons-tree")
CL-USER> (draw-cons-tree:draw-tree '(c ((b (x)) (d (a)))))
[o|o]---[o|/]
 |       |      
 C      [o|o]---[o|/]
         |       |      
         |      [o|o]---[o|/]
         |       |       |      
         |       D      [o|/]
         |               |      
         |               A      
         |      
        [o|o]---[o|/]
         |       |      
         B      [o|/]
                 |      
                 X      
NIL
CL-USER> (draw-cons-tree:draw-tree '(c ((b (x)) d a)))
[o|o]---[o|/]
 |       |      
 C      [o|o]---[o|o]---[o|/]
         |       |       |      
         |       D       A      
         |      
        [o|o]---[o|/]
         |       |      
         B      [o|/]
                 |      
                 X      
NIL
CL-USER>
```

Answer (score 0):

Transform any box diagram by recursively applying the same transformation:

```
[ * | * ] --->  B
  |
  |
  v
  A
```

becomes

```
( {A} . {B} )
```

where `{A}` means the diagram `A` transformed by the same procedure.

A special case is that `[ A | / ]` (writing it as a shorthand for

```
[ * | / ]
  |
  |
  v
  A
```

) is the same as

```
[ A | * ] ---> NIL
```

and a base case is `{NIL} === ()`.

The other base case is that anything not inside a box is just as it is.

It doesn't matter which way the arrow is drawn pointing, what matters is whether it starts from the first field of a box, or from the second field.

Your last diagram thus becomes

```
(c . { ...                                  })
(c . ( {...}             . { ...           }))
(c . ( {...}             . (d . { ...     })))
(c . ( {...}             . (d . (a . {NIL}))))
(c . ( (b . {...})       . (d . (a . {NIL}))))
(c . ( (b . (x . {NIL})) . (d . (a . {NIL}))))
(c . ( (b . (x . (   ))) . (d . (a . (   )))))
```

Having transformed your box-and-pointers diagram in full, you're left with a textual string representation of it. To simplify it by removing all the excessive dots and pairs of parentheses, finally apply the rule

```
(A B ... . (C ...))  ===  (A B ... C ...)  ;; NB nothing after (C ...)!
```

in a purely syntactical manner, repeatedly, anywhere inside the string that you can, until it can't be applied any longer. Just remove both the dot and the following pair of the matching parentheses around the last subexpression in a list together, at once. Both `B ...` and `C ...` sequences can be empty, or non-empty sequences:

```
(c . ( (b . (x . (   ))) . (d . (a . (   )))))
(c . ( (b . (x        )) . (d . (a . (   )))))
(c . ( (b . (x        )) . (d . (a        ))))
(c . ( (b . (x        )) . (d    a         )))
(c . ( (b    x         ) . (d    a         )))
(c . ( (b    x         )    d    a          ))
```

Or you could perform it in different order, as

```
(c . ( (b . (x . (   ))) . (d . (a . (   )))))
(c     (b . (x . (   ))) . (d . (a . (   ))) )
(c     (b . (x . (   )))    d . (a . (   ))  )
(c     (b . (x . (   )))    d    a . (   )   )
(c     (b . (x        ))    d    a           )
```

I've left one more step for you to perform, in both cases. The end result will be the same.